# Maximizing product of fractions

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to maximize $f(a,b,c) = \frac{a}{a+1}\cdot\frac{b}{b+1}\cdot\frac{c}{c+1}$, where $a,b,c$ are nonnegative integers and $a+b+c=30$. I began the problem with AM-GM to find an upper bound of 1000 for abc, but am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: If all you want is the numerical value, then why not just whip up a little program to exhaustively explore the $(a,b,c)$ triples? Even a ham-handed upper bound is that there are no more than ${32 \choose 2}= 496$ of them.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Lagrange Multipliers? They imply $a=b=c$. 

Note the constraint and the functions remained unchanged if any two of the variables are swapped. I seem to recall a theorem that suggests that implies $a=b=c$ as well.

Comment: I would ideally like to generalize this to $n$ variables, so no brute force. No Lagrange Multipliers.

Comment: Note the simple answer here is because of the sum restriction 30 being a multiple of the number 3 of variables. If the sum were 28 instead it seems one makes the vars as "equal as possible" something like 8,10,10 or 9,9,10. [the latter is better by a bit, but I didn't try other neighboring values.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $x,y,z$ instead of $a,b,c$ and setting the problem in 3d space, your function represents a surface which has a 3-fold rotational symmetry with respect to the line given parametrically by
\begin{equation}
x=t, y=t, z=t
\end{equation}
i.e. the "center" line of the first octant in 3d space.
Your constraint, $x+y+z=30$ or more generally $x+y+z=k$ is a plane orthogonal to that line.
From these considerations it follows that the solution you are searching lies at the point of tangency between your surface (the function you want to maximize) and the plane, in fact the surface
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{x+1}\cdot\frac{y}{y+1}\cdot\frac{z}{z+1}=k
\end{equation}
shifts away from the origin as $k$ increases.
To see this, try to sketch the similar function in the plane
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{x+1}\cdot\frac{y}{y+1}=k
\end{equation}
and you will see that the solution of your original problem must be such that
\begin{equation}
x=y=z
\end{equation}